# How to Solve Virtual Disk Service initialization failed Could not find a part of the path?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

When starting the Share and Store Management (SSM) mmc on a Win2k8 R2 server, it proceeds to list a few shares, then stops and I get the following error:

*Virtual Disk Service initialization failed Could not find a part of the path

Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\11\bjz3tssz.tmp'.*

Checking into that path, the directory 11 does not exist, so of course the temp files don't exist either.

Each re-opening points to the same user directory right down to the 11 directory, but the name of temp file changes to another seemingly random string of text.

I tried restarting the Virtual Disk Service, but that didn't help.
I'd like to restart the server, but cannot do that during working hours.

How do I fix it from wanting to check that path?

For a workaround, I created the 11 directory on that path, and the SSM will now list all the shares and I can work with them, but I still do get the error. I hate to leave an error unchecked.